# Pre-Calc question, please help.

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have to find a polynomial function of degree 4 with real coefficients with a real zero at i, a zero at -3(multiplicity 2), that passes through the point (-1,16). Please help.

Answer (score 3):

For polynomials with real coefficients, nonreal roots occur in conjugate pairs. Hence the polynomial is $f(x)=k(x+i)(x-i)(x+3)^2=k(x^2+1)(x+3)^2$. Now substitute $(-1,16)$ to find $k$.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1